# Add Id of created document in another document in mongoose

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nest

I want to save id of document after create to another document in same collection.
Is there anyway to do this, with just one query in mongoose?

Comment: not possible with just one query

Answer (score 0):

You can use the post middleware, in your model file :

```
    schema.post('save', function(doc) {
     otherDocument.save()
});
```

Then create a document but dont save it, so it will not have an Id_ .
Then you save the first document and that will trigger the save() inside de post functuion.

For mor info check the mongoose docs [mongoose post](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post)